# WordPress running within Docker instance, unable to write to file

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, ubuntu

I am completely new to docker. Just trying to run WordPress within a docker instance to learn more about it.

./public_html/ - has WordPress files and from the domain, I am able to access the installer. However the WordPress installer cant update wp-config.php within docker - as below error.

> Unable to write to wp-config.php file.

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        image: webdevops/php-apache:7.2
        container_name: web
        restart: always
        environment:
          - PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS=1
          - PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=2048M
          - PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=300
          - PHP_POST_MAX_SIZE=500M
          - PHP_UPLOAD_MAX_FILESIZE=256M
        volumes:
          - ./public_html/:/app
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
        links:
          - mysql
    mysql:
        image: mariadb:10
        container_name: mysql
        restart: always
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
        environment:
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=test
        volumes:
          - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    phpmyadmin:
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
#        environment:
#          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
#          - PMA_USER=root
#          - PMA_PASSWORD=root
        ports:
          - "8080:80"
        links:
          - mysql:db
        depends_on:
          - mysql

volumes:
    db-data:
        external: false
```

Now WordPress allow me to create the config.php. installation went on. I just tried to upload a plugin to test and I get below error. which I anticipated.

> Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2021/02. Is its parent
> directory writable by the server?

I logged into the docker "docker exec -it 51af15ed3678 bash" to check file permission.

```
root@51af15ed3678:/# ls -lart
total 104
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Nov 22 12:37 boot
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  9 23:22 srv
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  9 23:22 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  9 23:22 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Dec  9 23:22 lib64
drwx------   2 root root 4096 Feb 27 22:12 entrypoint.d
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   28 Feb 27 22:12 entrypoint.cmd -> /opt/docker/bin/entrypoint.d
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   29 Feb 27 22:12 entrypoint -> /opt/docker/bin/entrypoint.sh
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Feb 27 22:12 home
drwx------   1 root root 4096 Feb 27 22:31 root
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Feb 27 22:36 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Feb 27 22:36 lib
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Feb 27 22:36 bin
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Feb 27 22:36 var
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Feb 27 22:36 usr
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Feb 27 22:36 opt
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Feb 28 13:36 etc
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    0 Feb 28 13:36 .dockerenv
dr-xr-xr-x 197 root root    0 Feb 28 13:36 proc
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Feb 28 13:36 sys
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   12 Feb 28 13:36 docker.stdout -> /proc/1/fd/1
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   12 Feb 28 13:36 docker.stderr -> /proc/1/fd/2
srwx------   1 root root    0 Feb 28 13:36 .supervisor.sock
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  360 Feb 28 13:36 dev
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Feb 28 13:36 run
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root 4096 Feb 28 17:24 app
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Feb 28 17:28 ..
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Feb 28 17:28 .
root@51af15ed3678:/# cd app
root@51af15ed3678:/app# ls -lart
total 32876
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     3300 Feb  6  2020 wp-load.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     2496 Feb  6  2020 wp-links-opml.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     2913 Feb  6  2020 wp-config-sample.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      351 Feb  6  2020 wp-blog-header.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root      405 Feb  6  2020 index.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    19915 Feb 12  2020 license.txt
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     8509 Apr 14  2020 wp-mail.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     3236 Jun  8  2020 xmlrpc.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     7278 Jun 26  2020 readme.html
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     7101 Jul 28  2020 wp-activate.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     3939 Jul 30  2020 wp-cron.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    31337 Sep 30 21:54 wp-signup.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     4747 Oct  8 21:15 wp-trackback.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     2328 Oct  8 21:15 wp-comments-post.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    49831 Nov  9 10:53 wp-login.php
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    20975 Nov 12 14:43 wp-settings.php
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root    12288 Feb 22 15:10 wp-includes
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Feb 22 15:10 wp-content
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root     4096 Feb 22 15:10 wp-admin
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 16712083 Feb 22 15:10 latest.zip.1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 16712083 Feb 22 15:10 latest.zip
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     3181 Feb 28 17:24 wp-config.php
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Feb 28 17:24 .
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root     4096 Feb 28 17:28 ..
root@51af15ed3678:/app#
```

Any clue will be a great help. Thank you.

Regards,
Dwija

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is running the daemon under user `application` (UID 1000; GID 1000) so make sure all files are owned by the user `application` not `root`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Your reply is correct. 

`chown -R application:application ./app`   - I had to execute this within the docker image.

I need to run this every time I fire up the container. How can I do this in docker-compose ?

added this `command: bash -c "chown -R application:application ./app"` in docker compose, didn't work. the container wont come up, stuck in restarting status.

Comment: The command is a good workaraound, but better approach is to create your own Dockerfile to build an image with the proper setting or change the owner and group to 1000 of the content of your `./public_html` on your host. I would go for an image.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will work on that.